# Ruby equivalent to java BigInteger

Tags: java, ruby

I'm trying to match the precision of BigInteger from Java using the Ruby Programming Language.  Does anyone know of a Ruby equivalent of BigInteger?

Comment: If either answer below was helpful please select the one you prefer.

Answer (score 11):

Ruby handles it for you automatically:

```
1 << 32
# => 4294967296
1 << 65
# => 36893488147419103232
1 << 65535
# => 1001764965203...(lots of numbers)...859578368
```

There's no need for an explicit "bignum" type class since the regular Integer does it.

Comment: That begs the question (for us Java programmers): what is the Ruby equivalent of a 32 bit integer or an IEEE 754 floating point number?  Assuming one wants those specific semantics?

Comment: Ruby has strict Integer and Float values, but the Integer will shift its internal representation depending on the magnitude of the value and the Float is a wrapper around, I believe, a double.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov There's a [BigDecimal](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html), but it's a representation for fixed point, something that preserves accuracy and doesn't suffer from the same approximation problems as a float.

Answer (score 5):

All Ruby integers are big! Almost all implementations of Ruby have no (sensible) limit on integer values.

The interpreter auto switches between the FixNum and BigNum as needed.

Later versions of the language hide these implementation details, but the huge integer range is retained.

So use any old integer values and go to town!